# Erlang how to check if all elements in a list of tuples exists in another list of tuples

Tags: list, tuples, erlang

Say i have two lists: AmountOfProducts which has a list of tuples like

```
[{apple, 10}, {chocolate, 13}, {lettuce, 9}, {mango, 20}]
```

And the second list is the OrderProducts which has tuples like

```
[{apple, 3}, {chocolate, 1}, {mango 4}]
```

The first element is the atom for the name of the product, the second element is the amount, for AmountOfProducts the amount is the number available and for OrderProducts its the amount its asking for.
Is there a way to check if the all atoms of OrderProducts exists inside AmountOfProducts and return a true? And if, lets say  OrderProducts had an extra tuple and its atom  didnt exist inside AmountOfProducts for it to return false? The idea is something like this:

```
AmountOfProducts = [{apple, 10}, {chocolate, 13}, {lettuce, 9}, {mango, 20}]
OrderProducts = [{apple, 3}, {chocolate, 1}, {mango 4}]

check_products(AmountOfProducts, OrderProducts) ->
    if
        all atoms inside OrderProducts exists in AmountOfProducts -> true;
        one or many of the atoms inside OrderProducts doesnt exist in AmountOfProducts -> false
    end.
```

In the given case of the two lists it should come back as true. Is there a way to do this? I hope this makes sense, Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'll show you several ways to solve this problem.

### First Version: List Comprehensions

```erlang
check_products(AmountOfProducts, OrderProducts) ->
  [] ==
    [Key || {Key, _} <- OrderProducts
          , not lists:keymember(Key, 1, AmountOfProducts)].
```

Here we basically collect all the keys in `OrderProducts` that don't have a corresponding tuple in `AmountOfProducts` and, if that's an empty list… we return `true`

### Second Version: High-Order Functions

```erlang
check_products(AmountOfProducts, OrderProducts) ->
  lists:all(
    fun({Key, _}) ->
      lists:keymember(Key, 1, AmountOfProducts)
    end, OrderProducts).
```

Here we basically write what you wrote in your question, but in Erlang code: Return `true` if the keys of *all* the elements in `OrderProduct` are also keys in `AmountOfProducts`.

### Third Version: Just compare the Keys

Now, if you know that there will be no duplication of keys in any of the lists, you can also write your code like this…

```erlang
check_products(AmountOfProducts, OrderProducts) ->
  [] == keys(OrderProducts) -- keys(AmountOfProducts).
```

Basically saying that if we remove all the keys from `AmountOfProducts` from the list of keys of `OrderProducts`... we end up with no keys (they were all removed because they belonged to `AmountOfProducts`).
You have to implement an auxiliary function `keys/1`, but that one is hopefully much easier to implement (or you can just use [`proplists:get_keys/1`](https://www.erlang.org/doc/man/proplists.html#get_keys-1).

Comment: In order to scale well in case you do this on longer lists of items, it is best to use `ordsets:from_list(proplists:get_keys(List))` on both lists, then `ordsets:subtract(Set1, Set2)` instead of `--`, and check if the result is `[]` as before. This avoids the quadratic time you will get otherwise.

Comment: Great solution!